# Can I write an AWS lambda function that is triggered from an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to trigger execution of an AWS Lambda function from within an EC2 instance.  Or in parlance of AWS Lambda, my event source is code running inside EC2 instance.

The [list of supported event sources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-functions.html) does not quite tell me how to use an event inside an EC2 instance to trigger a lambda function.

I basically want to do something like provisioning a new instance when an application parameter exceeds watermark level.

Yogesh Devi

Comment: Yes, you can invoke Lambda functions from within EC2 as long as the instance has appropriate permissions (via IAM role). However, it looks like you are basically trying to create your own Auto Scaling solution. Why not just use Auto Scaling (with your custom CloudWatch metric)?

Answer (score 1):

Application code running anywhere on the Internet (including an Amazon EC2 instance) can call the lambda [Invoke](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html) command to trigger a Lambda function.